# Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View' when using Gesture via function

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to extract my gesture out to a function for use within one of my Swift Packages. The issue I'm having is that when I attempt to use it on one of my views, it doesn't conform to View anymore.

The following code produces this error: `Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'`

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Placeholder")
        } 
        .gesture(swipeDownGesture())
    }

    func swipeDownGesture() -> any Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local).onEnded({ gesture in
            if gesture.translation.height > 0 {
                // Run some code
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a lot of difference between the keywords `some` & `any`. `some` is returning any type of `Gesture` that doesn't change, like if it is a `DragGesture`, it should always be that. Whereas any returns a type of `Gesture` that is not set to always be `DragGesture` gesture for example.

In your case, replacing `any` with `some` does the trick.

Edit:
`any` is more like a cast working as a Type eraser. `some` is for associated type, acting more like generics. For more info, check [this](https://www.donnywals.com/whats-the-difference-between-any-and-some-in-swift-5-7/) out.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it and worked! Will accept your answer once able to.

Answer (score 5):

use `some` instead, `some` indicates for compiler to infer concrete type from whatever is generated and returned inside:

```
func swipeDownGesture() -> some Gesture {   // << here !!
    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local).onEnded({ gesture in
        if gesture.translation.height > 0 {
            // Run some code
        }
    })
}
```